# So the GNU getopt only supports options in the middle?

Tags: c, gnu, getopt

I'm trying the `getopt` API:

http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt

But I find it only supports options in the middle?

As I find that it's judging `argv[optind]` to `argv[argc-1]` as non-opt arguments.

Is that the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GNU getopt allows options anywhere on the command line. It re-orders `argv` when parsing, though. You can verify this by saving the example code in a file, compiling it, and running the result:

```
./a.out
./a.out -a
./a.out foo
./a.out -a foo
./a.out foo -a
```

The last two will give the same results.

Comment: is it true that `getopt` can only deal with single char options?

Comment: Use `getopt_long` for long option names. Follow the "next" link from the example page you linked to for more info.